# unknown regexp options - gdrad

Tags: sinatra, nokogiri

I am relatively new to parsing and would like to get more practice.  I want to parse the following url address: http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/hard-work

Here is my code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "open-uri" #open the file on the internet
require "nokogiri" #takes the file and translate it so that we can use it in ruby


page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(http://goodreads.com/quotes/tag/hard-work))
puts page
```

When I run this in ruby, I get the following error message:

```
trial.rb:6: unknown regexp options - grad
```

Can someone please tell me what this error message means? I have looked online but cannot find anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you've given should be a string, but without the quotes the double slash makes Ruby's parser believe it's a regex you've given. Try:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://goodreads.com/quotes/tag/hard-work"))
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand how to work with both nokogiri and Xpath? I need a little help understanding how to select the elements I want and would appreciate some feedback. Let me know if its okay to post information on the document I am working with and I will edit my question above. Thank you

Comment: @MsUzoAgu I've no problem doing that, but I think you'd be better off using an xpath tutorial and then posting new questions for the specific problems you find along the way, as you'll attract more interest in the questions that way. Try opening the document in IRB and testing stuff in there, you'll get quite far that way.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! Started doing your suggestion already and have already posted one question on here.  I definitely need more practice and will strive to more problems. Once again, thanks for following up.